# Generate MySQL data dump in SQL from PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm writing a PHP script to generate SQL dumps from my database for version control purposes. It already dumps the data structure by means of running the appropriate `SHOW CREATE ....` query. Now I want to dump data itself but I'm unsure about the best method. My requirements are:

- I need a record per row
- Rows must be sorted by primary key
- SQL must be valid and exact no matter the data type (integers, strings, binary data...)
- Dumps should be identical when data has not changed

I can detect and run `mysqldump` as external command but that adds an extra system requirement and I need to parse the output in order to remove headers and footers with dump information I don't need (such as server version or dump date). I'd love to keep my script as simple as I can so it can be hold in an standalone file.

What are my alternatives?

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm trying out SHOW INDEX and mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: mysqldump doesn't really add an extra system requirement, it ships with mySQL.

Comment: So mysqldump adds MySQL as system requirement. Most devs around here don't have a local server: they connect to the common server in the LAN.

Comment: If MySQL is running on the common server and your script is also running on the common server, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Are you sure that versioning data using home made dumps is a good idea? I like the idea of versioning the schema, but data?

Comment: @banzaimonkey: I can't follow you. We all code in our respective PCs. We don't even log into the server where MySQL is running.

Comment: @newtover: then, what's your proposal for, e.g., keeping a table with country names? Typing them every time?

Comment: @Álvaro: Perhaps you could clarify your team's development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mysqldump output parsing is still the easiest. I think there are really few meta-data you have to exclude, and thus dropping those should be only a few lines of code.

You could also look at the following mysqdump options: --tab, --compact

Answer (score 0):

Could always try the system() function. Hope you are in linux :)

Comment: There are systems outside Linux as well :)

Answer (score 0):

"Select * from tablename order by primary key"
you can get the table names from the information_schema database or the "show tables" command. Also can get the primary key from "show indexes from tablename"
and then loop and create insert statements strings